# »... Vertauschung der beiden Farben in irgend einem Wappen.« : is that only a "mix-up" (on one coat of arms)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammatical-number

> Vielleicht hängt dieser wechsel zusammen mit einer *vertauschung* der beiden farben in irgend einem wappen.
>
> [ *Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch* (FEW), [*sinopis*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/235491), top of second column ]

The *Beolingus* dictionary gives, for [*Vertauschung*](http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=%20vertauschung%20&iservice=), *permutation*, *transposition*, *inversion error* and *mix-up*. I would like to know whether from context<sup>1</sup> the native speaker understands anything else than those, as in "*perhaps this change is related to a mix-up with two colors in whatever crest*", or whether you can also read this to mean an "occurrence" of both colors in a single (or even between two, as I can't tell whether [*Wappen*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-american/wappen) is grammatically plural here because of *irgend* or by default) crest/coat of arms?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm briefly exploring the use of some colors in French heraldry. In [*blasonnement*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasonnement), that is the textual description of what is represented graphically, the word [*sinople*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sinople) is used to denote the green color. But before it meant green it used to mean red (nowadays [*gueules*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gueules/2) means red). The explanation in the *TLFi* (French dictionary) relies on the *FEW* :</sub>

> <sub>[...] a désigné d'abord la couleur rouge, puis par un changement de
>   sens *inexpliqué* la couleur verte (peut-être est-ce lié à une
>   **intervention** des deux couleurs dans un quelconque blason? v. FEW, loc. cit.).</sub>

<sub>The highlighted word doesn't mean *inversion/mix-up* but rather the *concurring action* (the *intervening*) of both colors on whichever coat of arms. I suspect they wanted to write [*inter**version***](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/interversion) (a French word meaning *the swapping of, permutation*), and therefore *inter**vention*** would be a typo. So I'm checking the source (*FEW*) but have no experience whatsoever with the language. Sadly I can't speak/read German, so I had to put this to [***Translate***](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Die%20vorliegenden%20farbennamen%20sind%20enthlent%20aut%20latin.%20Der%20antike%20name%20stammt%2C%20dass%20diese%20rote%20erdart%20%28eisenocker%29%20uber%20der%20hafen%20Sinope%20nach%20dem%20westen%20gelangte.%20Das%20wort%20findet%20sich%20meist%20him%20heraldischen%20sinn.%20Eigentumlich%20ist%20dabei%2C%20das%20die.%20bed.%20wechselt.%20Zuerst%20ist%20sie%20%22rot%22%20von%20der%20zweiten%20halfte%20des%2014%20jhs%20an%20%22grun%22.%20Vielleicht%20hangt%20dieser%20wechsel%20zusammen%20mit%20einer%20vertauschung%20der%20beiden%20farben%20in%20irgend%20wappen.%20Die%20endung%20-ople%20erklart%20sich%20vielleicht%20%20aus%20den%20deklinierten%20formen%20von%20sinopsis...%20Die%20bed.%20%22rot%22%20lebt%20aber%20in%20ubertragungen%20im%2017-19%20jhs%20weiter.%20Aus%20der%20fr.%20entlehnt%20sp.%20sinople.%202%20ist%20eine%20jungere%20entlehnung%20der%20altertumwissenschaft.%0A%0A1%29%20In%20einer%20anzahl%20von%20texten%20ist%20eine%20sichere%20entscheidung%2C%20ob%20die%20bed.%20%22rot%22%20oder%20%22grun%22%20vorliege%2C%20unmoglich%2C%20so%20bei%20Thomas%2C%20im%20Erec%20von%20Chrestien%20...%20Die%20oben%20gemachten%20%20chronologischen%20ansatze%20mussen%20daher%20mit%20einen%20gewissen%20vorbehalt%20aufgenommen%20werden.) after trying as best as I can to re-transcribe the text from the entry. The word abbreviated with "bed." must be [Bedeutung](http://Bedeutung), "meaning" from what I can tell. I have also found that *Google* wouldn't translate *eigentumlich*, but the aforementioned [dictionary](http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=Eigentumlich&iservice=) makes me think this must be an adverb as in "oddly/strangely". — To summarize my reading of a dictionary referencing the *FEW* in another language cast a doubt about the meaning of the sentence I presented in introduction, especially since I only have access to its machine translation because I have no knowledge of the language.</sub>

Comment: Remember, that nouns (like »Vertauschung«, »Wechsel«, »Farben«, »Wappen«) in German language **ALWAYS** have to be written with an uppercase first letter. I corrected that for you.

Comment: The way i understand it the author speculates about two colours being involuntarily exchanged. I'm not sure that *mix-up* transports that so clearly.

Comment: @Burki: Isn't that exactly what is expressed by *mix-up*? I was rather concerned that *mix-up* fails to express the colour switch may have been intentional (*Vertauschung* can be both deliberate or accidental).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i don't trust my english enough to say for certain if it does, so i thought i'd jsut add the details

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Die falsche Schreibweise stammt aus dem Original.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm grateful for the edits to bring this on par with the standards of the language. Indeed the _FEW_ doesn't have the uppercase (I think that's what the comment above refers to) ; I dared not ask why. I used "mix-up", G Translate provided me initially with "reversal" and someone says "exchange" here; whatever it may be I want to make sure it's not "co-occurrence".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is mostly correct. I would translate the sentence as

> Perhaps this change is related to a mix-up of these two colors in some crest.

I'm actually not certain whether the author is speculating about an error that happened when creating a description of a crest, misnoming the colors, or an actual change in the colors of said crest that lead to confusuin due to outdated descriptions still being used.

Comment: Thank you ! So basically you're saying this is easily translated but that doesn't immediately tells us what might have happened (the speculation you describe). Do you confirm that the sentence refers to only _one_ crest? Do the words preceding _Wappen_ hint that we're talking about one specific historical crest that the author might have seen?

Comment: I don't think that the author has seen anything suspicious that might qualify for the cause of the change in meaning, no. He is not talking about a specific crest, just speculating that it might have happened in **a** crest. The sentence only mentions *one* (unspecified) crest, that's why I chose "in some crest" to translate "in irgend einem wappen" (modern spelling would be "in irgendeinem Wappen").

Comment: Thank you! I'm happy I got some help to look into what Mr Walther von Wartburg wrote (the FEW is such a masterpiece); I guess in the end an inversion error with two colors might be construed more generally as an event involving the two colors and maybe that's what the TLFi meant. Also this was my first introduction to the German language and I learned quite a few things!

Answer (score 1):

When you translate "Vertauschung" with "mix-up" or "inversion error" you use (negative) connotations the word "Vertauschung" doesn't necessarily have. "Vertauschung" could as neutral as "exchange", "interchange" or "reversal" and, depending on context, these might be better translations. "Mix-up" implies that something has gone wrong whereas "exchange" doesn't.